# Symfony2 store variables in session

Tags: php, symfony, session

first of all, i'm working with symfony 2.0.20... and I have problems with the session. I'm doing that:

Get the session service:

```
$session = $this->get('session');
```

Save the vars (obviously criteria have some value):

```
$session->set('criteria', $criteria);
```

And I get the var like this:

```
$criteria = $session->get('criteria');
```

But, I never no data inside... any idea?
And, in the chrome/firefox inspector I don't see anything and the "var_dump" the same...

Any help will be appreciated

Roger

Comment: are you sure that session_start() was called before?

Comment: in the oficial documentation [link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) says it is not necessary... but I try it

Comment: @n-dru doesn't work... :(

Comment: sorry, I don't know Symphony, I was just guessing the most common reason for missing session variables...

Answer (score 0):

did you start your session
$session = new Session();
$session->start();

Comment: if I do that I have the next error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\SessionStorage\SessionStorageInterface, none given

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to `use`

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

This is how I start a session in Symfony2

```
$session = $request->getSession();
```

This is how i set it

```
$session->set('products', $products);
```

This is how i get it

```
$session->get('products')
```

and in my config.yml

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 86400
        gc_maxlifetime: 1800
```

I hope this helps.